# Number of homomorphisms from $A_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I'm trying to calculate a number of homomorphisms from alternating group $A_4$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.

We can generate entire $A_4 = \langle a , b \rangle $ with two elements: $a =(12)(34), b = (123)$ where $a^2=(), b^3=()$ and $(ab)^3=()$. To my understanding it is enough to define homomorphism on the set of generators respecting these relations.

$f:A_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is homomorphism if for every $x,y \in A_4$: $f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)$. So because of $(ab)^3=()$ we have $0=f((ab)^3) = 3f(a) + 3f(b) = f(a)$. And since order of $f(x)$ has to divide order of $x$ the only possibilities are: $f(a) = 0$ and $f(b) \in \{0, 4, 8\}$.

So including the trivial one it seems that there are only 3 such homomorphisms. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: You are well on your way, but you need to verify that all the choices for $f(b)$ give rise to a homomorphism After all, there may be other relations satisfied by $a$ and $b$ that complicate the matter further. A bit more generally: $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ is abelian. This implies that for all $x,y\in A_4$ the commutator $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is in the kernel of any homomorphism $f:A_4\to\Bbb{Z}_{12}$. First show that the commutators generate a subgroup of four elements $K$, whence $A_4/K\simeq C_3$. The rest is easy.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your comment. I've edited my response into the question as it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4304997/121097) I have explained how to use $\ker f$ and the normal subgroups of $A_4$ in order to find all possible morphisms.

Clearly $\ker f$ can't be trivial, since then $f$ is an isomorphism which is false.

If $\ker f=A_4$ you get the trivial morphism.

The third case is $\ker f=\{(1),(14)(23),(13)(24),(12)(34)\}$.

If $\sigma\in A_4$ is a $3$-cycle, say $\sigma=(1\ 2 \ 3)$, then $A_4=K\cup\sigma K\cup\sigma^2 K$ (disjoint union), where $K=\ker f$. This shows that knowing $f(\sigma)$ is enough to determine $f$ completely. But $3f(\sigma)=\hat 0$, and thus $f(\sigma)$ can only be $\hat 4, \hat 8$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm trying to digest it now. So I was correct in saying there are 3 such homomorphisms.
(1) I understand that by using hats (e.g. $\hat 0$) - you're just distinguishing elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and nothing more, right?
(2) Also is there a reason why you removed $\hat 0$ as a possibility for $f(\sigma)$? Or is it just because it's accounted for in the case of trivial morphism?
I'll probably accept this answer soon, just need to think about it some more.

Comment: (1) Right. (2) I removed $\hat 0$ since I was in a case which doesn't allow the trivial morphism whose kernel is $A_4$. In this case the kernel was $K$.

Comment: I went through all of it a couple of times again and I think the last doubt I have is on why exactly $A_4 = K \cup \sigma K \cup \sigma^2 K$ implies that knowing $f(\sigma)$ is enough to determine $f$. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I've thought that this is obvious from the form of elements of $A_4$: $\sigma^ik$ with $i=0,1,2$ and $k\in K$. Since $f$ has to be a morphism and $\ker f=K$ we define $f(k)=\hat 0$ and $f(\sigma^ik)=f(\sigma)^i$ for $i=1,2$.